# PG::ConnectionBad FATAL: database "myapp_development" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, postgresql-9.2

I'm using Heroku and following the tutorial about rails.

When I type `$ foreman start` I encounter below error.

```
PG::ConnectionBad
FATAL: database "myapp_development" does not exist
```

I access `psql` and then `createdb myapp_devleopment`. After type these and then type again `foreman start`, I also have same problems. What I have to do?

Answer (score 2):

Given that you mispelled the name in your question, make sure you didn't mispelled it in your system as well.

It should be

```
myapp_development
```

not

```
myapp_devleopment
```

Answer (score 1):

in your local folder(where your app is) just run 
    `createdb name` ,where name is the name of the database it is said it's missing``